# Circular Motion of speedboat towing water skier

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics, circular-motion

I'm confused about the following simple circular motion question.

A water skier of mass 100 kg is being towed by a speed boat, the length of the tow rope being 30 meters. Boat and skier are moving with constant speed in concentric circles of radii of 40 meters and 50 meters respectively.  The total mass of the boat and its occupant is 300 kg and its speed is 8 m/s while the speed of the skier is 10 m/s.  Assuming that the tow rope is horizontal and the total air and water resistance is proportional to the square of the speed (with the same constant of proportion for both boat and skier), find the tension in the tow row and the magnitude and direction of the force driving the speed boat.

Attached is a diagram I have constructed for the scenario. The friction of the skier is $F_s$.  The friction of the speed boat is $F_b$ and the tension of the tow rope is $T$.  The direction of motion is shown in the diagram.

[image]

My question is:  Why is the driving force of the speed boat at an angle to the tangent?

The answer to the question is.

$ 519 N $ at $ \tan^{-1} \dfrac{46}{16}$ with tangential direction.

However I think this answer is incorrect.

Comment: For uniform circular motion the force points toward  the center of the circle.

Comment: If that is the case then the driving force of the speed boat would be $90^{\circ}$ to the tangent.

Comment: That is correct. See [this](https://www.vedantu.com/physics/uniform-circular-motion).

Comment: But that is not the answer.

Comment: That is because you have frictional forces. You don't have uniform circular motion.

Comment: Ok... since there is a friction force acting on the speed boat, there is no uniform circular motion as a result the driving force for the speed boat is not directed towards the centre BUT at an angle to the tangent.  Is my logic correct?

Comment: Yes,  your logic is correct.

Comment: Thanks John.... I thought as much, but yu just confirmed it.  Thank-you for commenting.